# How to use the python method "ImageDataGenerator" and save the augmented images in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, data-augmentation

I'm constructing an augmented database to improve my CNN. The scheme is:

- I send an image, one per time, to generate another 40 images.
- The quoted method saves the augmented images in a directory, but I want to save them in a variable without saving them firstly in my computer. That is, I want to save directly in a variable.

The code above shows what I'm talking about. Take a look at the parameter "save_to_dir"... If I neglect it the processing is made but the data isn't saved anywhere.
Can anyone help me?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

IMAGE_PATH = "---"
OUTPUT_PATH = "---"

image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
plt.imshow(image)

image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

imgAug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=360, width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.20, fill_mode='wrap',     horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True)

imgGen = imgAug.flow(image, save_to_dir=OUTPUT_PATH,
                     save_format='png', save_prefix='dentezudo_')

counter = 0
for (i, newImage) in enumerate(imgGen):
    counter += 1

    if counter == 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `.flow()` returns a generator that you can iterate over (like you do in your code) to get your images. In your code, the augmented images will be assigned to `newImage`.

According to [the docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), `flow()` can also save the images to disk:

> save_to_dir: None or str (default: None). This allows you to
>   optionally specify a directory to which to save the augmented pictures
>   being generated (useful for visualizing what you are doing).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I got "newImage" and applied in a vector "images=[]" as "images.extend([newImage])" over each loop and it works. Good comment helped me!!!

Comment: Thank you! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.